# How to paginate a data table that is rendered via AJAX in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to render a Blade template in Laravel that contains an HTML table with data obtained via AJAX, and need to manually paginate the results using Laravel's LengthAwarePaginator.

I have a main blade file called **reports.blade.php** which contains an AJAX call to a controller method called **SalesController@get_sales_forecast**. Within that controller, I am fetching some data from a MSSQL database and rendering a partial view called **sales-forecast-table** that puts the data in an HTML table. That is all working successfully.

However, I am now trying to paginate those results because the data set is very large.

In my main blade file (reports.blade.php), the AJAX call looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url:'{{action('SalesController@get_sales_forecast')}}',
   data: {
         _token: $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content'),
         start_date: $('#txtStartDate').val(),
         end_date: $('#txtEndDate').val()
  },
  success:function(data) {
         $('#table-sales-forecast').html(data.html);
  }
});
```

Furthermore, reports.blade.php includes a partial view:

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="table-part-forecast-annual">
    @include('sales-forecast-table')
</div>
```

The AJAX call goes out to SalesController@get_sales_forecast, which looks like this:

```
public function get_sales_forecast(Request $request) {

        //Get data from Sales model
        $sales_forecast = Sales::getSalesForecast($start_date, $end_date);

        //Get current page
        $current_page = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

        //Create new collection
        $item_collection = collect($sales_forecast);

        //Define how many items to show per page
        $page_limit = 25;

        //Slice the collection to get the items to display in current page
        $current_page_items = $item_collection->slice(($current_page * $page_limit) - $page_limit, $page_limit)->all();

        //Create paginator 
        $paginated_items = new LengthAwarePaginator($current_page_items, count($item_collection), $page_limit);

        //Set URL path for generated links
        $paginated_items->withPath($request->url());

        //Render the view as an HTML string
        $html = view('sales-forecast-table')->with(['sales_forecast' => $paginated_items])->render();

        //Return the HTML 
        return response()->json(compact('html'));
    }
```

And the view being rendered from the AJAX call (**sales-forecast-table.blade.php**) looks like this:

```
@if(isset($sales_forecast))
    {!!$sales_forecast->links()!!}
    <table class='table table-hover table-striped table-bordered'>
        @foreach($sales_forecast as $record)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$record->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$record->location}}</td>
                <td>{!!$record->customer!!}</td>
                <td>{!!$record->forecast!!}</td>
        @endforeach
    </table>
@endif
```

At this point, the table does render and the page links even appear. The table only displays the first 25 rows as expected (per the `$page_limit = 25` line) with page 1 selected, but when I click on any of the other page links, I simply receive a "No message" error. The error message is so vague that I'm not quite sure where to go from here. Perhaps I am using AJAX within Laravel in an overly complicated way? I was trying to stick to the conventions of the framework as much as possible, but I am open to trying it a different way if that would make this problem easier.

Comment: Are the links rendered within your `$paginated_items` set up to load via ajax on click? Where are these links supposed to go when clicked?

Comment: I guess that's where I am stuck at. Normally, on pages where I am not using AJAX to get data, clicking on the page link that is rendered by Laravel's built in pagination simply reloads the current page but with the next set of data shown and adds a page number to the URL. For example, if the address to the page is www.example.com and the user clicks '2', the page reloads as **www.example.com?page=2**. And if the limit for the page was set to 25, it would show the next 25 rows of data.

Comment: What I'm not sure how to do is set the page links up where they will recall SalesController@get_sales_forecast. I'm sure it's something simple but because there's so many layers, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to do it.

Comment: @thisiskelvin Forgot to @ you, this is my first time posting a question on here, so I'm a bit of a noob. :)

Comment: Why are you paginating things twice? You are doing once on your collection and again with the laravel class.

Comment: @JedLynch I am only calling Laravel's paginator once. The `$current_page_items` line is just slicing the array to get the needed subset of data, which is then past into Laravel's `LengthAwarePaginator` class, as this class takes a subset of data, total number of items in the whole dataset, and the current page number as parameters.

Comment: You are slicing the data and paginating it.  So you are paginating it twice. It looks like the constructor of the LengthAwarePaginator is supposed to take all the items, and the paginator does the rest. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.php#L41 
 https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.php#L288

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `getSalesForcast` is a scope so it should return a collection.  I would recommend using `forPage`.  I am not 100% sure how you are getting your start date and end parameter in the request, but given those values this should work.  Also, I am assuming you are using timestamps.

```
const $page_limit = 25;

public function get_sales_forecast(Request $request) {

    //Get current page
    $current_page = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

    //Get data from Sales model
    $sales_forecast = Sales::where('created_at','>',$request->input('start_date'))
                      ->where('created_at','<',$request->input('end_date'))
                      ->forPage($current_page,self::$page_limit)
                      ->get();

    //Create paginator 
    $LengthAwarePaginator = new LengthAwarePaginator($sales_forecast, $sales_forecast->count(), self::$page_limit);

    //Set URL path for generated links
    $paginated_items->withPath($LengthAwarePaginator->url($current_page));

    //Render the view as an HTML string
    $html = view('sales-forecast-table')->with(['sales_forecast' => $LengthAwarePaginator->items()])->render();

    //Return the HTML 
    return response()->json(compact('html'));
}
```